# Why is ag-Grid clearing filter after being set in onGridReady

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am experiencing strange behavior where if I set a filter model in the onGridReady event it is deleted afterwords. I've been logging the filterChanged events and I see it being called when i set the filter but it is never being called again yet the filter is cleared without a filter changed event. when I was using community I didn't experience this but when i upgraded to enterprise and started using the setFilter this began happening. any ideas?

```
    onGridReady(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
        this.gridApi = params.api
        this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit()
        this.resetDefaults()
        window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                params.api.sizeColumnsToFit()
            })
        })
    }

    resetDefaults(): void {
        this.gridApi.setFilterModel({
            ColorStatus: {
                filterType: 'set',
                values: [ColorStatus.red.toString(), ColorStatus.yellow.toString()]
            }
        })
        this.gridApi.onFilterChanged(); //I've tried with and without this line
    }
```

Oddly when I set sorting in onGridReady the sort model is not affected only the filter models get cleared.
In the mean time I've moved resetDefaults() to the onFirstDataRendered event but this is not ideal because the user will see all data for a moment then before it 
 gets filtered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My coworker found that adding `newRowsAction: 'keep'` to the filterParams of the column in question resolves the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try with below approach instead of setting `filterModel` using `gridApi.setFilterModel`.

1. Get the filter instance of the `Column` using `colId` (set it while defining `ColDef`)
2. `setModel` using the filter instance.

```
// define filterModel
const filterModel = {
   ColorStatus: {
      filterType: 'set',
      values: [ColorStatus.red.toString(), ColorStatus.yellow.toString()]
   }
};

const filterInstance = this.gridApi.getFilterInstance(colId); // <- ColorStatus column columnId
// you need to set it inside ColDef for this column

filterInstance.setModel(filterModel);
```

Comment: Using setModel from the filter instance seems to have the same problem unfortunately

Comment: Could you give a plunk reproducing the issue?